# olivetti misbehaving on save, in org buffers

Tags: org-mode, hooks, olivetti-mode

I'm getting this very strange behavior while using olivetti: when calling save-buffer the display goes back to the left margin, as if olivetti has stopped working. If I call olivetti-mode, it shows that it's still enabled, and it stays to the left until I zoom in or out (ctrl-+ on doom).
I only get this behavior in org buffers..

Is it possible that there's an after-save-hook that only runs in org mode? how can I check that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try `C-h v after-save-hook RET` and see the value of the hook, if that's where the problem could be.

Comment: thanks!
I have:
`(+vc-gutter-init-maybe-h
 org-roam-db-update
 org-roam--handle-title-change
 flycheck-handle-save
 t
 ws-butler-after-save)`

non of which look suspicious

Comment: You say you are using Doom. Does olivetti behaves the same from `emacs -Q`? If so, you should report it as a bug at https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue in Doom Emacs. In my case, When I edited `.mdx` file in `olivetti-mode` and used the save-buffer command, Emacs would exits olivetti-mode.

After I switched from 'fundamental-mode' to 'text-mode', the issue disappeared.

---

I managed to gather some clues by enabling debug-on-entry on the set-window-margin function, which is called by olivetti-mode.

Following this, Emacs entered debugger mode, presenting a backtrace associated with the `doom-guess-mode-h` function.

I suspect that Doom Emacs is attempting to determine the most suitable major mode for the buffer when it is in fundamental mode.

I hope this helps someone.